# Yaf Framework based application doesn't run

Tags: php, model-view-controller, ubuntu

I'm setting up YAF php for a small application. Issue is that I've installed it as per the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/yaf.examples.php) however the sample application doesn't run and aI get a Yaf_Application not found error. I think I have installed yaf correctly as running:

```
php -m | grep yaf
```

returns `yaf`

However a phpinfo doesn't show any listing of YAF anywhere. Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 2):

By the Ubuntu tag, I'll assume you're using a stock Ubuntu installation of PHP5... Double-check to ensure that you have an yaf.ini file in your conf.d directory:

> /etc/php5/conf.d/yaf.ini

or

> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/yaf.ini

Within the file, you should should have, at a minimum:

> extension=yaf.so

If you are using a custom install, double check phpinfo() and verify the file path to the php.ini file.